# 'Uploads' object is not iterable in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to have each model object have it's own page with all the other model objects attached to it, using the modal id, I tried using the {{ img.queryset.all.id }} html tag to display the photo, but that didn't work. I know the problem is in either the views.py or single_page.html, and maybe the models.py but I believe that is unlikely the problem. When I click onto the photo it bring it to a page with the photo icon, it doesn't display it because the photo is unknown. While every time I use {% for x in img %} it says 'Uploads' object is not integrable. If anyone could help that would be great.

modals.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = False, blank = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'default.png', upload_to = "img/%y", null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'



class Uploads(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500, null = True,)
    artiste = models.CharField(max_length=500, null = True,)
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    time_length=models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2,blank=True, null = True,)
    audio_file=models.FileField(upload_to='musics/',validators=[validate_is_audio], null = True,)

    caption = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to = "img/%y", null = True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = None, null = True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True, null = False)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file) and f"{self.id}"

class Album(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

views.py

```
def profile(request, user):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile_id = request.user.profile)         #Make sure only your account *images stays on the page
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    context = {"profile": profile, "img": img}

    return render(request, "main/profile.html", context)

def single_page(request, id):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(id = id).first()    
    profile = Uploads.objects.filter(id = request.user.id)

    context = { "img": img, "profile": profile}

    return render(request, "main/single_page.html", context)
```

single_page.html

```
{% block content %}
<body>

    {% for x in img %}
    <p>{{title}}</p>

    <img src="{{x.file.url}}" height="100%" width="100%"  class="myImg">
    {% endfor %}


</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `img` is a single `Uploads` object, not a list of objects.  Why would you expect it to be iterable?

Comment: My logic was that it is the only way to grab an item, if there is only one item in the array, you just have to iterate once to get the item *image*.

Comment: Is there a way I can just get the item without for looping it? I tried {{ img.queryset.all.id }}, but that did not work.

Comment: I assume `{{ img.file.url }}` will work

Comment: That didn't work, thank you for the attempt though, I think I have to use instance in my views.py, would instance be a way to grab it without the iteration?

Comment: do you sure that django serve your media files properly?

Comment: I think you need a double underscore, `img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile__id = request.user.profile)`

Comment: @raphael that's not right. You won't filter by `id` when you pass `Profile` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are filtering through the profile by id and also specifying first it wouldn't be possible to loop through as first would render the first object and so the loop will only work with you adding (img.all) by doing something like this:

```
# Your view.py 
def single_page(request, id):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(id=id)    
    profile = Uploads.objects.filter(id = request.user.id)

    context = { "img": img, "profile": profile}

    return render(request, "main/single_page.html", context)
```

Your Html

```
{% block content %}
<body>
    {% for x in img.all %}
    <p>{{title}}</p>

    <img src="{{x.file.url}}" height="100%" width="100%"  class="myImg">
    {% endfor %}

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

If `img` is an object, you cannot iterate over it, so `for` loop is not valid idea. You should be able to access it's url with: `{{ img.file.url }}`.

Don't use `id` as variable, it's builtin function. Don't filter `Uploads.id` by `request.user.id` because it's not going to work. It's different model.

For single photo you should do in `views`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def single_page(request, img_id):
    img = get_object_or_404(Uploads, id=img_id)

    context = {"img": img}

    return render(request, "main/single_page.html", context)
```

single_page.html:

```
{% block content %}
<body>

    <p>{{ img.title }}</p>

    <img src="{{ img.file.url }}" height="100%" width="100%"  class="myImg">

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

If you have more pictures of one `User`, you can find them with:

```
images = Uploads.objects.filter(profile=self.request.user.profile)
context = {"images": images}
```

And in template:

```
{% for img in images %}

    <p>{{ img.title }}</p>

    <img src="{{ img.file.url }}" height="100%" width="100%" class="myImg">

{% endfor %}
```

And if you want to get `profile`, don't search it with `filter`, because you will get `QuerySet`, not an object instance. To get single object you should do as I've showed you before:

```
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
# or
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

or if you really, really prefer `filter` method:

```
profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
```